# Short story about a man filling gas on a planet where aliens used to live

Tags: story-identification, aliens, space

So there's a population of humans living on a planet in space (I forgot the name of the planet). There's this guy filling up gas and he's late for a party (if I remember correctly). He spots a alien in the distance (I think there was a war and the humans killed them all). He follows the alien, not knowing its a ghost. Alien takes him to alien burial site or where it died but guy sees what the life of aliens looked like before they were killed and hes amazed how wonderful it was.

That's the jist of it. If anyone can tell me the name or author of the short story, that would save me a lot of head scratching. Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think that's from *The Martian Chronicles* by Ray Bradbury.

August 2002-Night Meeting

Tomás is on his way to a party and stops at a gas station. He meets a Martian driving a vehicle; each thinks the other is a ghost.

"Tomás encounters a Martian named Muhe Ca. Each can see the Mars he is accustomed to, in his own time frame, but the other person is translucent to him and has the appearance of a phantom. The young man sees ruins where the Martian sees a thriving city, while the Martian sees an ocean where Tomás sees the new Earth settlement." -Wikipedia

Story here:
http://kenstonlocal.org/novak/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Bradbury-August-2002-Night-Meeting.pdf